# discrete mathematics combinatorics - counting

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> I have $52$ cards from $4$ series ($13 \times 4=52 \text{ cards}$). Each series are
>   numbered from $1$ to $13$. In how many possible ways you can draw from the
>   deck $6$ cards, so that all your six cards has two numbers exactly?

**My answer:**

**First card** - $\binom{13}{1} \cdot \binom{8}{4}$ (choosing from the $8$ possibilities, $4$ places I can put my cards. choosing $4$ because I can't have more than $4$ cards of the same number)

**Second card** - $\binom{13}{1} \cdot \binom{7}{4}$ (same, but $7$)

**Total** - First card + Second card

Not quite sure about my answer. I am pretty sure I am counting more than there is. Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The number of different  ways  to  obtain $2$ out of $13$ different  numbers is
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{13}{2}
> \end{align*}

Next we  consider all valid configurations which can be obtained with two numbers.

> Since there are always four cards with the same number and we take six cards from the deck there are three types of valid configurations
>
> - $(4,2)$:  Four cards with the first number and  two  cards with the second number. There are
>     \begin{align*}
>   \frac{6!}{4!2!}=\binom{6}{2}
>   \end{align*}
>     different configurations of this type.
> - $(3,3)$: Three cards with the first number and three cards with the second number , giving
>     \begin{align*}
>   \frac{6!}{3!3!}=\binom{6}{3}
>   \end{align*}
>     different configurations.
> - $(2,4)$:  Two cards with the first number and  four  cards with the second number, giving $$\frac{6!}{2!4!}=\binom{6}{2}$$ different configuration as in the first case.

We conclude:

> There are 
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{13}{2}\left(2\binom{6}{2}+\binom{6}{3}\right)=3900
> \end{align*}
>   different configurations to draw six cards with two numbers from the deck.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong here or miss something, but the OP question is about the number of possibilities to draw six cards that has two numbers exactly.

Comment: @SalechAlhasov: Thanks for the hint. Wording corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly understanding this to be asking "how many ways can you draw 6 cards from a standard 52 card deck such that no more than two unique values are represented in the hand" then the answer is 
\begin{align*}
\binom{13}{2}*\binom{8}{2} = 2184
\end{align*}
Explanation:
\begin{align*}
\binom{13}{2}\end{align*} selects which two values the hand will contain.
\begin{align*}
\binom{8}{2}\end{align*} chooses which of the 8 cards that have those two values will actually be in the hand. This is assuming that we do not care about the order of the cards in the hand.

Comment: I believe your way is under-counting.  Well picking the six cards have a few cases.  For example, let's say I pick number 2 and 3.  I can have four 2's and two 3's, two 2's and four 3's, or three 2's and three 3's.

Comment: All of those cases are accounted for by the (8 choose 6). In your example the 8 cards being chosen from are 2H, 2C, 2S, 2D, 3H, 3C, 3S, 3D. Choosing 6 of them could give us 2H, 2C, 2S, 2D, 3H, 3C (4 twos, 2 threes) or 2S, 2D, 3H, 3C, 3S, 3D (2 twos, 4 threes) or any other combination.

Comment: It is possible that I am misunderstanding something, but Markus's answer appears incorrect to me. For example, you say there are 6 choose 2 = 15 ways to select 4 of the first number and 2 of the second, but there are only 6: you have all 4 of the first number, and your choice of any 2 of the second, giving 4 choose 2 = 6.

Comment: @Rance: The suits are not considered in the problem. So, we don't consider $2H, 2C, 2S, 2D$, but four two's $2222$ instead. I think there are $\binom{6}{2}=15$ different configurations with four $1$'s and two $2$'s on the deck: $111122,111212,111221,112112,112121,112211,121112,121121,121211,122111,211112,211121,211211,212111,221111$

Comment: @Markus: Ok, I understand what you are saying. Your answer is correct if the order of the draws matters and the specific cards drawn does not. I understood the question to be asking how many unique 6-card hands meeting those conditions could be drawn from the deck (the question you would need to answer if you wanted to then calculate the probability of drawing such a hand).